# how to load multiple songs/tracks into pygame?

Tags: pygame

Is there a way to load multiple songs into Pygame? I'm not talking about sound effects like this;

```
crash_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("crash.ogg")
#and
pygame.mixer.Sound.play(crash)
```

because I know you can have multiple different sound effects, assigned to different variables, obviously. But I'm talking about the music function in pygame (this one):

```
pygame.mixer.music.load("chill_music.ogg")
#and
pygame.mixer.music.stop()
```

because you can't assign it to variables, or anything, you just set the mixer.music thing to one ogg file and can't have more.
I need this feature, because it let's me set it to a '-1' value making it play over and over again, which I'm pretty sure you can't do with the sound effects, but I want two different songs for two different levels.
I hope it makes sense.
Thanks

Comment: It's possible to loop sound-effect/music on a Pygame mixer channel.  As you say, just give it a `-1` as the second argument.  `mixer_channel1.play( level_music, -1 )`.  There's no distinction between an short sound effect and a longer "music" sound effect in the API.  I'm under the impression that the `pygame.mixer.music` interface is there to work with MP3s, but I may be speaking in ignorance here.  So if you're using .OGGs anyway, there's no issue.

Answer (score 2):

> I need this feature, because it let's me set it to a '-1' value making it play over and over again, which I'm pretty sure you can't do with the sound effect

Actually, [you can](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound.play):

> `play()`
>      *begin sound playback*
>      `play(loops=0, maxtime=0, fade_ms=0) -> Channel`
>
> The loops argument controls how many times the sample will be repeated after being played the first time. ... If loops is set to -1 the Sound will loop indefinitely (though you can still call stop() to stop it).

So you can use the `Sound` class.

> but I want two different songs for two different levels

Nothing stops you from calling `pygame.mixer.music.load(...)` again with another sound file. It will stop playing the current file and start the new one.

[Note:](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html)

> The difference between the music playback and regular Sound playback is that the music is streamed, and never actually loaded all at once...

So if your music files are rather big and you don't want to store them in memory, using `pygame.mixer.music` is the way to go. If you don't mind loading the files completely, you can use the `Sound` class.