# How can I play two songs at once using Pygame.mixer.music?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, pygame, python-multiprocessing

I have to make a player that can play two songs simultaneously.
The problem is that the only module that I could find that supports every sound manipulation method that I need to use is Pygame.mixer.music. Unfortunately it only supports a single music stream at once.

I tried to cheat the system using threads and multiprocessing but it didn't do the job.

My question is does anybody know a Python3 module that can play 2 songs at once and has the following possibilities: pause, stop, seek through the song, change volume and change speed of the song.
Or does anybody know how to do this with the Pygame module.

The multiprocessing code that I tried to use is down below if anybody can help with this I'd be grateful!

```
import pygame
import multiprocessing

pygame.mixer.init()


def play(arg):
    pygame.mixer.init()
    if arg:
        print(arg)
        pygame.mixer.music.load('song1.ogg')
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
    else:
        print(arg)
        pygame.mixer.music.load('song2.ogg')
        pygame.mixer.music.play()


p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=play, args=(True,))
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=play, args=(False,))
p1.start()
p2.start()

while True:
    pass
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to load multiple songs/tracks into pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59817691/how-to-load-multiple-songs-tracks-into-pygame)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get the job done.
At the moment I am using 2 sound manipulation modules:

- Pygame.mixer.music
- python-vlc

They are working properly together and have the functions that I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any threading or multiprocessing. You can just paly 2 songs parallel using the [`pygame.mixer.Sound`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound) objects:

```py
import pygame

pygame.mixer.init()
song_1 = pygame.mixer.Sound('song1.ogg')
song_2 = pygame.mixer.Sound('song2.ogg')
song_1.play(0)
song_2.play(0)

while pygame.mixer.get_busy():
    pygame.time.delay(10)
```

Comment: The pygame.mixer.Sound object does not have pause and seek options that are necessary for what I am supposed to do.

Comment: @aon2003 The pygam.mixer module has a `pygame.mixer.pause` method. No pygame module has a seek. So there is no solution to your question. I apologize that I've tried to help you.